# Converting Plotly Dash html into static email report

Tags: python, html-email, plotly-dash

I've built a nice looking report via Plotly Dash & Bootstrap, which I've just been developing locally (VS Code and local browser). I'd like to snapshot the static html and send it in the body of an email. What's the best pattern for this? Thank you all for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

On the website of plotly community, chriddyp(Co-founder of Plotly, Author of Dash) said :
"This isn’t supported as is. Dash components serialized as JSON data structures that are passed to the Javascript front end and turned into HTML tags with Javascript. There isn’t a way to convert these components into HTML tags directly in Python."

Answer (score 0):

"With the [Dash Enterprise Report Engine](https://plotly.com/dash/snapshot-engine/), you can create, annotate, archive, and share point-in-time views of your Dash apps.

With only a few lines of code, Report Engine adds powerful capabilities to your Dash apps:

Share a link to point-in-time Dash app views
Trigger email and PDF reports programmatically
Enable on-demand snapshots through the Dash app UI
Automate nightly snapshots to archive Dash app state
Draw or comment directly on the Dash app canvas, then share by email."